# can't remap C-v in emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp

I want to remap Control-v for it to use my custom function, but it looks like I can't do that. I'm running emacs in terminal.

```
(global-unset-key "\C-v")
(global-set-key   "\C-v"    'my-cut-or-paste)
```

If I try to unset first, C-h k just not showing any binding for this shortcut, and C-v just do nothing. If not unsetting shortcut, its not get remapped... The strange thing is how C-h k showing different keys for such shortcuts. For example - one time it can show

> r runs the command self-insert-command, which is an interactive

other time (after emacs reload)

> i runs the command self-insert-command, which is an interactive

If I try to set my function to such keys (i or r), C-v gets remapped, but those keys (i or r) are mapped to my function too, so I cant type.

Is this kind of 'terminal-related' key sequences? Is it able to do at all?  thx.

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be that your terminal is intercepting C-v as a paste-from-clipboard command.

If your clipboard has something that starts with i, you see:

```
i runs the command self-insert-command, which is an interactive
```

Similar for "r" or other letters.  Emacs is blind to the fact that the "letters" come from a external paste, not from your keyboard.  You should check the configuration options of your terminal, to see if you can unset that key.

Comment: Ok, looks like you right - i remapped paste in terminator config to other keybinding, and all works now. The problem is that now to paste from clipboard to terminal I have to use other key... Maybe I can make it work somehow to save the same shortcuts for both emacs and terminator? I actually use tmux, no ideas if it can be done there?